# Python can't open file

Tags: php, python, apache, permission-denied

I have a PHP script that is supposed to execute a python script as user "apache" but is returning the error:

`/transform/anaconda/bin/python: can't open file '/transform/python_code/edit_doc_with_new_demo_info.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Permissions for `edit_doc_with_new_demo_info.py` are `---xrwx--x. 1 apache PosixUsers 4077 Sep 18 12:14 edit_doc_with_new_demo_info.py`. The line that is calling this python script is:

`shell_exec('/transform/anaconda/bin/python /transform/python_code/edit_doc_with_new_demo_info.py ' . escapeshellarg($json_python_data) .' >> /transform/edit_subject_python.log 2>&1')`

If `apache` is the owner of the python file and the owner has execute permission how can it be unable to open the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python interpreter has to open the file for *reading*, so both the execute and read bits are required. Try this:

```
$ chmod 550 /transform/python_code/edit_doc_with_new_demo_info.py
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume the same occurs with any interpreter of sort (e.g. PHP)

Comment: Practically speaking, yes, all interpreters require read permission of their script files.

Comment: Oh wow, I never would have guessed that. So you need read access whenever a script calls another script or only when you are passing something between scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You need read permission to run the python script.